# Exception handling and rollbacks in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, exception, rollback, plsqldeveloper

Currently I have one table FIRST_ENTRY_TABLE with PLAN_A and other 11 tables have respective customer_ID with respect to PLAN_A.I have a temp table with new Key which will replace PLAN_A and add PLAN_B for respective customer_is's.
Below are 12 PL/SQL Procedure which is inserting/updating new PLAN_B into all required tables with respect to customer_id.
As there is around 100 000 PLANS which will be replaced by NEW PLAN KEY for customer_ids.

Firstly I am creating cursor and reading all new KEYS to be updated in 12 tables.

Then respectively inserting/updating query in 12 tables through 12 Procedures.

```
DECLARE
var1
CURSOR C1
select query fetching PLAN_B key from temp table
PROCEDURE procedure1(
P_key IN OFFTABLE%TYPE;
IS
BEGIN
INSERT into FIRST_ENTRY_TABLE( 
mandator_key,OFFER_TYPE_KEY,offer_key)VALUES('abc','FIXED',P_key)
RETURNING ID
INTO var1;
 END procedure1;
 )
PROCEDIRE procedure2(
 P_key IN OFFTABLE%TYPE;
 oldid IN FIRST_ENTRY_TABLE%TYPE;
 )
IS
 BEGIN
 INSERT into SECOND_ENTRY_TABLE(col1,col2...custid)
 select (col1,col2...var1) FROM sometable WHERE offer_key= P_key;
 UPDATE SECOND_ENTRY_TABLE set custid=var1 where custid=oldid;
 END procedure2;

 simplarly procedure3

 procedure4..  procedure5

 --------procedure12
 COMMIT;
```

My question is how to do exception handling here as I have all insert and update statements.
   I know to use NO_DATA_FOUND,what all other exceptions could come and how can we handle it here.
   How to handle exception, In the end after all procedures execute and COMMIT or inside every procedure?

How can I take rollback from all 12 tables? there would be delete script for new inserted keys and update query for PLAN getting updated in few tables.but there would be over 100k records. Is there any way to write procedure to take rollback before execution of procedures?

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BobJarvis I am trying to use dynamic SQL.Just to brief you,I have total 12 different tables where id is autogenaerated for a PLAN,I am trying to update PLAN A to PLAN B according to temp table(like temp table has new plan keys),so I created a cursor C1 for the same to read dynamically all new keys and respectively update in 12 Procedures for updating Plan Key in 12 tables. My query is I am not aware how can I take rollbacks from all 12 Tables

Comment: @BobJarvis Like suppose while updating in alltables something dosnt go well then i have to exec rollback and delete the inserted queries and reupdate the query in order to rollback.Also how can i handle exceptions here.I am not aware of exc through PL/SQL so need suggestion as in how could I include it for insert and update queries in all 12 tables.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like `lakh`.

Answer (score 1):

your code seems very messy.. To practice exception handling in PL/SQL- try to write your sql query within begin, exception and end block. you can do it within loop as well according to the need of your data.

```
DECLARE
   lv_qry varchar2(100):=NULL;
   lv_param1 varchar2(100):=NULL;
   lv_param2 varchar2(100):=NULL;
BEGIN
   lv_qry:=''; --your or update query 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_qry into lv_param1 using lv_param2; --Bind the variable 'optional'
   COMMIT;
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
      ROLLBACK;
 END;
```

Comment: Your sample code uses dynamic SQL. There's no reference to dynamic SQL in the original question. If you are deliberately advising the OP to use Dynamic SQL then please expand your question to explain what benefits the OP will gain from this approach. Otherwise please edit your response to fit closer to the OP's posted code.

Comment: @APC yes I am trying to use dynamic SQL.Just to brief you,I have total 12 different tables where id is autogenaerated for a PLAN,I am trying to update PLAN A to PLAN B according to temp table(like temp table has new plan keys),so I created a cursor C1 for the same to read dynamically all new keys and respectively update in 12 Procedures for updating Plan Key in 12 tables.        My query is I am not aware how can I take rollbacks from all 12 Tables.

Comment: @APC Like suppose while updating in alltables something dosnt go well then i have to exec rollback and delete the inserted queries and reupdate the query in order to rollback.Also how can i handle exceptions here.I am not aware of exc  through PL/SQL so need suggestion as in how could I include it for insert and update queries in all 12 tables.

Comment: @Atul Kr Dey thanks.I have two questions1.When I am writing 12 different Procedure for updating/inserting in 12 different tables and writing COMMIT in end of exec of all procedures then Exception block should be there for all 12 blocks or at last after COMMIT.2.what kind of exceptions can be there for insert and update statements in all procedures?Can we directly use predefined exceptions of oracle.

Comment: @lisa14 - please **edit your question** to make it clear what you are trying to achieve and what you want from us. Comments are for, um, comments: most people who read your question probably won't scroll down to read the comments thread on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all the updates, etc are performed during a single transaction, a single ROLLBACK will roll back all the changes made in the transaction. A transaction is automatically started when you perform a DML operation (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, DELETE) when no transaction is in effect; you can also start one using the SET TRANSACTION statement.